# Substituting multiple variables in a list using a VSTS Release Definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am currently using variable substitution in VSTS however I have hit a roadblock on how to select specific elements from a list.

I must supply both a name for the variable I want to substitute and a key with which to substitute the old value. I can use `.` to select nested elements in config.

I have the following app.config.

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Application.Project01">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="web" contract="Application.Interface01">
      <identity>
        <dns value="dns01" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Project01/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Application.Project02">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="web" contract="Application.Interface02">
      <identity>
        <dns value="dns01" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Project02/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

I would like to be able to substitute variables in each one of these services individually. The specific keys I am interested in are `services.service.endpoint.identity.dns.value` and `services.host.baseaddresses.add.baseaddress`.

I have tried the following to edit the dns value

- `services.1.service.endpoint.identity.dns`
- `services.1.service.endpoint.identity.dns.value`

The task that I am using is the Azure App Service Deploy version 3.*

Comment: What task or script you used to substitute?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Sorry! I forgot to add that, Azure App Service Deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [XML variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts#xmlvarsubs) feature of Azure App Service Deploy task, it takes effect only on the applicationSettings, appSettings, connectionStrings, and configSections elements of configuration files.

So you can’t use it to achieve your requirement.

You can try it with XML Transformation.

You also can try it with other tasks, such as [Release Management Utility tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) or [others](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=token&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

Comment: Is `system.serviceModel` not a config section though? Thanks for the alternatives! I'll give them a shot. Do you know if the task should occur before or after the Azure App Service task? The artifact is a zip file if that matters.

Comment: system.serviceModel is not the supported element. For other token task(s), it should be occur before Azure App Service task, and you also need to extract the zip file before token task.